# xpath find value of current node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have several nodes with same Name='UPC' and I need to find the value of the current one.

```
<XML>
<Attribute>
      <Name>UPC</Name>
      <Type>ComplexAttr</Type>
      <Value>Testing</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>UPC</Name>
      <Type>ComplexAttr</Type>
      <Value>24a</Value>
    </Attribute>
</XML>
```

**Expected Output:**
It should pull the value from /Attribute/Value where Name='UPC' and Type = 'ComplexAttr'.

On the first run = 'Testing' &
On the 2nd run the value should be = '24a'

I'm trying to use the following code but it is not working. The value is null.

```
<xsl:attribute name ="value">
    <xsl:value-of select =".//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'][$i]/Value" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

where **$i** is the variable I'm using to loop through the above xml and it increments after each run. However, it only gives me the same value '**Testing**' (which is the first value) in every run. I have checked the value of the variable. It is changing every time it loops through.

I have also tried using current() and position() like below but I'm getting null in this case.

```
<xsl:value-of select =".//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'][current()]/Value" />

<xsl:value-of select =".//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'][position() = $i]/Value" />
```

Can someone help me out with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the expected output for this XML sample?

Comment: @Alejandro. I have added the expected output above. Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and quick, one-liner XPath expression solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is one of the biggest FAQ**:

The `[]` operator binds stronger than the `//` abbreviation.

**In order to select the 1st element in the XML document, that satisfies the specific condition in the predicate, use**:

```
(//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'])[1]/Value
```

**In order to select the 2nd element in the XML document, that satisfies the specific condition in the predicate, use**:

```
(//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'])[2]/Value
```

**In order to select the `$i`th element in the XML document, that satisfies the specific condition in the predicate, use**:

```
(//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name = 'UPC'])[position() = $i]/Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works like a charm ... :-). I will accept your answer and +1 for the explanation. Which is very important for a newbie in XSLT like me ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable in an XPath expression.  Try manually using a constant and you'll see that it works:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr' and Name='UPC'][2]/Value" />
```

In general, you don't really write loops in XSLT, even though the syntax allows it. You write templates that are invoked with a particular context at a particular point in time. I'm not sure what the best next step is without knowing more about the context of the overall program.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct. Since the constant is giving the output then technically variable should do the same. And that is why I was trying to use the variable. I'm new to XSLT and due to time constriant right now I can't spend much time on XSLT to figure things out. I have tried to do it recursively but it is not working. So I switched to iteration. If you like you can view my earlier post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638460/xslt-grouping-recursive-problem-part-2. If you have any input/idea in how to fix my issue then let me know. Thanks